# Matplotlib circle (ellipse) with two different line styles

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot

I've been trying to plot an ellipse (circle) with two different sections, represented by two different line styles. Because I am plotting an ellipse with 3D coordinates in a 2D space, I want the portion of the ellipse, with Z<0, to be a different line style and for Z>0 yet another line style. However, I end up with a line running through the middle of the ellipse. Here is a short portion of my code and a sample image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class orbels:
    import numpy as np
    def __init__(self,a,e,i,O,w):
 #       import numpy as np
        self.a=a
        self.e=e
        self.i=i*np.pi/180
        self.O=O*np.pi/180
        self.w=w*np.pi/180
    def kep2cart(self):
        cos=np.cos
        sin=np.sin
        pi=np.pi
        theta=np.linspace(0,2*pi,500)
        x=np.zeros(len(theta))
        y=np.zeros(len(theta))
        z=np.zeros(len(theta))
        for j,t in enumerate(theta):
            R=self.a * (1.-(self.e)**2)/(1+self.e * cos(t))
            x[j]=R*(cos(self.O)*cos(self.w+t)-sin(self.O)*sin(self.w+t)*cos(self.i))
            y[j]=R*(sin(self.O)*cos(self.w+t)+cos(self.O)*sin(self.w+t)*cos(self.i))
            z[j]=R*sin(self.w+t)*sin(self.i)
        return x,y,z

jup=orbels(5.2,0.048,1.3,100,14.8)

x5,y5,z5=jup.kep2cart()

plt.plot(x5[z5<0],y5[z5<0],'r--')
plt.plot(x5[z5>0],y5[z5>0],'r-',lw=2)
plt.plot(0,0,'ko',markersize=3)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlabel('X [AU]')
plt.ylabel('Y [AU]')
plt.xlim(-6,6)
plt.ylim(-6,6)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The snippet above produces the following figure
[image: Ellipse Plot]

There is a line running through the middle of the ellipse. I guess, the part where the ellipse is drawn with a continuous line, the data points jump from one end of the figure to the other, causing matplotlib to connect the points.
One way to overcome this issue is instead of using lines I could use points but then I need a whole lot of points to represent the continuous part of the ellipse.
Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `x5[z5<0]`, you create a shorter array, with all positive z-values filtered away. `plt.plot()`  will connect the points in the order they are encountered, which can lead to the superfluous diagonal line.

With a [mask](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html), on the contrary, the arrays keep their original lengths, and `plt.plot()` skips the missing segments.

```py
from numpy import ma

plt.plot(ma.array(x5, mask=z5 < 0), ma.array(y5, mask=z5 < 0), 'r--')
plt.plot(ma.array(x5, mask=z5 > 0), ma.array(y5, mask=z5 > 0), 'r-', lw=2)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and elegant solution. I wasn't aware of the "ma" module in numpy!